# PDFBox: problems with the fonts and loctions of added texts

Tags: pdf, fonts

I added new texts to a exiting PDF, but the fonts and locations are way off. The location should be 100, 500 with the testing codes. But it shows up at around 10, 50 with extremely small font instead of 12.

I checked the internal structure of the pdf with iText Rup and found that the mediabox of the pdf has (0,0,612,792). However, the existing streams show very strange coordinates, for example:

```
0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0 cm
BT
/F1 70 Tf
0 6600 Td
3001 -6274 Td
0 Tw
(© All rights reserved.) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 70 Tf
0 6600 Td
2365 -6274 Td
0 Tw
(Page 1 of 4) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 70 Tf
0 6600 Td
180 -6274 Td
0 Tw
```

It looks like that the font size in the stream is 70, which is not the case (the font size should be around 7). And the coordinates such as 6600 are way beyond the mediabox. I would guess that may the reason that the newly added texts show up in wrong locations and smaller fonts.

DO you know if there are ways to adjust the font size and locations so that they show up at correct locations and font size?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here are the testing codes:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(file));

    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;

    List<PDPage> pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
    PDPage page = pages.get(0);

    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, false);
    contentStream.setFont( font, 12);
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 500);
    contentStream.drawString("hello, this is a test" );
    contentStream.endText();

    contentStream.close();

    document.save( "c:/temp/test.pdf");
    document.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your favourite PDF reference. The very first line,

```
0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0 cm
```

sets a basic transformation matrix for the rest of the page at a scale of 12/100ths. At that scale, the font sized "70", scaled, comes out at 8.4 pts. To get your own text at a size of 12pt, use 12/0.12 = 100 (scaled *units*, not "actual points"). Do the same for your position coordinates.

Comment: Thanks so much for such quick response, Jongware.  Are there utilities in PDFBox to get this transformation matrix?  Thanks again.

Comment: @user2254613: Typing it into Google, I got [the reference for PDGraphicsState](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/PDGraphicsState.html) as the first hit: use getCurrentTransformationMatrix.

Comment: @user2254613 To make use of `PDGraphicsState`, though, you have to parse the content stream(s). Unless you have to do so anyway, the easier way may be to envelop existing content with **q** and **Q**.

Comment: Does this look okay to get the scale? float getScale(PDPage page) throws IOException{

  float scale = 1.0f;
  PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page.getContents().getStream() );
  parser.parse();
  List tokens = parser.getTokens();
  for( int j=0; j<tokens.size(); j++ ){
   Object next = tokens.get( j );
   if( next instanceof PDFOperator ){
    PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator)next;
    if("cm".equals(op.getOperation())){//0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0 cm
     COSFloat theScale = (COSFloat)tokens.get( j-6 );
     scale = theScale.floatValue();
     break;
    }
   }
  }

  return scale;
 }

Comment: Unfortunately the **cm** Operation may appear multiple times, and the current state is not simply the last appearance but instead the product! Furthermore rotation might be involved. In that case you might look at the wrong value altogether.

Comment: @user2254613: (a bit late) welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) some time. You might want to choose "accept" on ansers you like.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following constructor when creating the content stream with resetContext set to "true":

```
public PDPageContentStream(PDDocument document, PDPage sourcePage, boolean appendContent, boolean compress, boolean resetContext) throws IOException
```

This will reset the context by enveloping the existing content with q and Q.